# Obj-C - Array returned empty upon tableview selection (sometimes)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm populating a tableview with results pulled from Google Places. For the most part, it works great. However, every so often when I tap a selection (didSelectRowAtIndexPath), my app crashes, stating that searchArray is empty.

> -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array'

I log it, and it is correct. However, this doesn't happen EVERY time I make a selection, only every so often does the searchArray appear to be empty when I tap a selection. Any idea why the searchArray is being cleared sometimes upon reaching didSelectRowAtIndexPath? See code below.

**UPDATE!** **I just discovered the cause of my crash.** It appears as though if I put in more than a certain number of characters, Google Places returns 0 results to the searchArray, resulting in a crash. However, if I only type in 3 characters and then tap a result, searchArray is populated. Any idea how I can enable searching with more characters?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)LoadJson_search{

    searchArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]mutableCopy];
    //    NSLog(@"str......%@",strSearch);
    // This API key is from https://developers.google.com/maps/web/
 /*   NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&types=street_address&location=49.266912500000004,-123.09886619999999&radius=2500000&strictbounds&key=MYKEY", strSearch];*/

    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=%@&types=street_address&location=49.266912500000004,-123.09886619999999&radius=25000&strictbounds&key=MYKEY", strSearch];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str1];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error=nil;
    if(data.length==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *jsondic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        //         NSLog(@"1,,,,%@",jsondic);
        [searchArray removeAllObjects];
        if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"])
        {

        }
        else if([[jsondic objectForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"INVALID_REQUEST"])
        {
        }
        else
        {
           for(int i=0;i<[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] count];i++)
            {
                NSString *str1=[[[jsondic objectForKey:@"predictions"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
                [searchArray addObject:str1];
            }


            self.tableView.hidden = NO;



            //            NSLog(@"%@", searchArray);
        }
        if (searchArray.count == 0) {
            self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

//TableView delegates
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return searchArray.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSLog(@"TAPPED CELL %@", searchArray);

    self.addressField.text = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    self.tableView.hidden = YES;

}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? And never use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` to load remote data, especially on the main queue. Use `NSURLSession` and load the data properly in the background with good error handling.

Comment: Are you sure LoadJson_search() is not being called again from some place else? The quick fix to this is to check if searchArray is not empty/null in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But not a solution. You might see the data on the table. But there's a chance that the data is empty and [self.tableView reloadData] is not called. The table will look "populated" but searchArray can be empty at some point.

Comment: Hi @Anil - I just discovered the cause of my crash. It appears as though if I only use integers, Google Places returns results to the searchArray. However as soon as I start entering letters (e.g. 257 Local Street...), it returns 0 to the searchArray. Any idea how I can enable the search for characters?

Comment: It is not good practice to update datasource by "[searchArray removeAllObjects];" but not the ui. You have to update table whenever you update data source.